# Regular expression for fetching variables

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to fetch the variables inside a query. Variables are described in queries as: `$$ variable (description) $$`, so I'm using this [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function:

```
preg_match_all("/\$\$\s*[^\$]*\s*\(\s*[^\$]*\s*\)\s*\$\$/", $queryCode, $variables)
```

An example for this query would be:

```
Some code $$ variable (a description) $$ more code $$ variable2 (other description) $$;
```

But I'm getting no results with this query. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use single quotes. `\$` becomes `$` in double-quotes, which means "end of string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simpler regex for this:

```
\$\$\h+(\S+)\h+\(([^)]+)\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ0hL1/2)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/\$\$\h+(\S+)\h+\(([^)]+)\)/'; 
$str = "Some code \$\$ variable (a description) \$\$ more code \$\$ variable2 (other description) \$\$;"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the description too. How could I get it?